# Correct way to start applications on boot in Linux

Tags: linux, boot, automation

What is the correct way (if possible distribution agnostic) to start application automatically in Linux (Debian Wheezy)? In need to know two things. How to autostart generally, so that the application runs in background even before I log in, and the userspecific autostart, meaning the application gets started as soon as the user logged in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard way to start processes on system startup is using a script in `/etc/init.d`.  There should be a template in the directory.  These need to be linked to the appropriate `/etc/rcX.d` directories.  `man` pages for the required command should be already installed.

`upstart` is newer way to get `init` to start a process when the server starts.  If this is available the command `man upstart` should give you documentation.

Starting commands when you login can be done in your `.profile`.  You will want to end the commands with a `&` so that they run in the background.

Comment: Depending on the shell, it is probably `~/.bash_profile`, just to avoid any confusion for @DevNoob. BillThor has you off to a great start.